# ServerScriptService Script doesn't see changes of player value

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I want to create a mine pet system for a clicker. I create a value in player

Main script in ServerScriptService:

```
local genX=Instance.new("IntValue", player) --actual player multiply by pets
genX.Value=10
genX.Name="genPetX"
```

and I have script that change it every time I click on Pet(xClicks have every pet and means the x that it will add to click)

LocalScript in Pet:

```
    local player= game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Equip=false

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function() 
    if Equip==false then
        player.genPetX.Value+=script.Parent.xClicks.Value
        Equip=true
    else
        player.genPetX.Value-=script.Parent.xClicks.Value
        Equip=false
    end
end)
```

I even have label that changes every time genPetX changes and print some text

LocalScript in Label:

```
local localplayer=game.Players.LocalPlayer
localplayer.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.xPet.Text=localplayer.genPetX.Value

localplayer.genPetX.Changed:Connect(function ()
    localplayer.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.xPet.Text=localplayer.genPetX.Value
    game.ReplicatedStorage.getX:FireServer()
end)
```

Main script in ServerScriptService:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.getX.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    print ("I watched you chaaaaangeeedddddd")
end)
```

but when I click, even when the Label say that it changed,  it using default genPetX=10 Value

Main script in ServerScriptService:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.click.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
  player.leaderstats.Clicks.Value+=player.ClicksPerClick.Value*player.genPetX.Value
end)
```

I don't know what I need to change to it work, I have tried a little changes, but as you can read it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You've run into a common issue with [client-server replication](https://create.roblox.com/docs/projects/client-server). When the server changes something, like a value or the position of an object, it replicates that change to all of the clients. But, for security reasons, if a client changes something, that change *does not* replicate up to the server or to any other client.

So the issue with your code is that the server has created the IntValue, `genPetX`, however the client is the one trying to change its value. So, the value will change on your client, but the server will never see that change.  But you're on the right track with the solution, you need to use your RemoteEvent to request that the server change the IntValue's Value.

So create a RemoteEvent in ReplicatedStorage specifically for updating the `genPetX` value, name it something like `setX`, and follow these steps...

So in your main Script in ServerScriptService :

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

-- create the IntValues inside the Player when they join the game
Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local genX = Instance.new("IntValue", player) --actual player multiply by pets
    genX.Value = 10
    genX.Name = "genPetX"
    -- create any other values here...
end)

-- listen for when a client signals that they have clicked on a pet
ReplicatedStorage.click.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    local cpc = player.ClicksPerClick.Value
    local gpx = player.genPetX.Value
    player.leaderstats.Clicks.Value += cpc * gpx
end)

-- listen for when a client tells you to update the `genPetX` value, the client will tell you the amount
ReplicatedStorage.setX.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, amount)
    assert(type(amount) == "number")
    player.genPetX.Value += amount
end)
```

Then, in your Label's LocalScript :

```lua
local localplayer = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local genPetX = localplayer.genPetX

local label = localplayer.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.xPet
label.Text = tostring(genPetX.Value)

-- keep the label constantly updated with changes to the IntValue's Value
genPetX.Changed:Connect(function(newValue)
    label.Text = tostring(newValue)
end)
```

Finally, in your Pet's LocalScript, use the RemoteEvent to request that the server update your value : (I'm assuming this is in a Tool)

```lua
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local setX = game.ReplicatedStorage.setX
local xClicks = script.Parent.xClicks

local equip = false

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    -- when equipping, subtract xClicks otherwise add them
    local amount = if equip and -xClicks.Value else xClicks.Value

    -- tell the server to update the player's genPetX value by the amount specified
    -- NOTE : THIS IS INHERENTLY UNSAFE, DON'T TRUST THE CLIENT TO EVER TELL THE TRUTH
    setX:FireServer(amount)

    -- toggle the value for equip
    equip = not equip
end)
```